# Which ML algorithms can be used to optimize a weighted quadratic loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions, weights

I want to solve the following optimization problem:

$$ L = n^{-1} \sum^n_{i=1} w_i ( y_i - \tau(x_i))^2  $$

where $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ weights, $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ outcome data, $x_i$ features/covariates,  and $\tau$ an unknown function to be specified or approximated by a machine learning (ML) algorithm.

For example if we specify a linear model $\tau(x_i)=x_i' \beta$ with parameters $\beta$ the problem above reduces to weighted least squares estimation of a linear model. If we then add a regularization

$$L + \lambda ||\beta||_q$$

we obtain the Lasso model for $q=1$ and the Ridge regression models for $q=2$. Consequently the `R` function `glmnet` for example, allows for weights.

Now, we could extend our model for $\tau$ by including splines, for exmaple, to learn non-linear continuous functions and increase the flexibility of the model.

My question:  are there any models / ML methods outside this class to minimize $L$?

For example, random forests can be used to approximate $\tau$ if there are no weights, I believe. However, a weighted random forest I have not seen yet and the standard functions e.g. `randomforest` does not allow for weights. I **suppose** the regression type models for $\tau$ (Ridge, Lasso, Spline, etc.)  are the only ones that apply here but I am very curious if anybody can point to ML methods that work with weights.

Comment: $L$ can be expressed as an unweighted model merely by multiplying all $y_i$ and $\tau(x_i)$ by $\sqrt{w_i}.$

Comment: @whuber Yes, but $\tau$ is unknown (unless specified as in a regression model) and the function approximator would still need to take the weights into account in the term $(\sqrt{w_i} \tau(x_i))$

Comment: Right: once you estimate $\tau,$ divide it by the roots of the weights.

Comment: @whuber I am not certain if I understand. Do you suggest to estimate a ML model with outcomes $\sqrt{w_i} y_i$ and obtain $\tau'(x_i)$ and then obtain $\tau$ by dividing $\tau'(x_i)$ through $\sqrt{w_i}$

Comment: The most popular solution algorithm for nonlinear least squares problems is arguably the Gauss Newton method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

Comment: Your question is about optimizing $L.$  If you have an unweighted optimizer, it will find the solution I describe.  Whether that's useful might depend on how $\tau$ is described in the solution.  It will work for regression models.